# Correction of wrong data

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I have the following data set:

```
  {{2, 25.4359}, {4, 25.1367}, {6, 24.8248}, {8, 24.8872},  
   {10, 24.7134}, {12, 24.3019}, {14, 23.2648}, {16, 22.7794}, 
   {18, 22.0979}, {20, 10.3315}, {22, 9.7597}, {24, 20.087}, 
   {26, 7.748}, {28, 17.3949}, {30, 5.952}, {32, 16.0672}, 
   {34, 15.084}, {36, 13.8762}, {38, 12.9525}, {40, 12.0011}, 
   {42, 11.1282}, {44, 10.1519}, {46, 9.56525}, {48, 8.80683}, 
   {50, 8.18156}, {52, 7.02375}, {54, 6.96017}, {56, 6.20118}, 
   {58, 5.57019}, {60, 5.82191}, {62, 5.61341}, {64, 5.40499}, 
   {66, 5.22668}, {68, 5.27839}, {70, 5.83658}}
```

[image]

Some of the data (red) in the range `20 < x 30` are too small (between 5 and 10) and have to be corrected to fit with the other data (blue).

How can this be achieved, without manually selecting the misplaced data?

I found that `ClusterClassify` can be used to distinguish the "wrong" data from the rest, but it could be accidental:

```
cl = ClusterClassify[data, 2, Method -> "Spectral"];

ListPlot[Pick[data, cl[data], #] & /@ {1, 2}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red} ]
```

[image]

Comment: *...have to be corrected...* If you intend to adjust the datapoints, you should have an idea of the error you wish to correct. From what I can see, the outliers are shifted downwards by a constant. Is that the case? Besides that, the use of `ClusterClassify` looks good, but it is likely to stumble on more difficult cases.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: One solution is probably after data separation to fit the blue data points and then to shift the red data points vertically upward so that they lie on the fitting curve.

Comment: In that case `f = Interpolation[blue]; shift = (f /@ red[[;;,1]] - red[[;;,2]] // Mean); red[[;;,2]] += shift; data = Join[red,blue]//SortBy[First]`. To move forward with an answer to your question a decent set of training data is necessary to optimize the parameters for `ClusterClassify` or a similar function that will detect outliers.

Comment: For the *specific* dataset you could fit (as in regression) a sigmoid or some other relatively well behaved function and replace observations '*far*' from the mean, with the mean; you should decide how *far* is 'far' eg one deviation.

Comment: Just to expand on the point made by @LLlAMnYP...Any adjustment method that doesn't acknowledge or account for the actual process that produces the points to be corrected is likely to fail.  One needs to define both what an "outlier" is and an "inlier".  Here is a recent but more complicated example (that is still unanswered):  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329170/need-advice-on-change-point-step-detection?noredirect=1#comment623834_329170.

Comment: @JimB: Thanks a lot for this link. It is very much similar to my "real problem" data. I tried to simplify it to be able to start with something simple.

Comment: It's not an easy question to answer.  And even answers that duplicate what one would do by eye (which aren't necessarily the right thing to do) are difficult to mimic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The procedure below finds the outliers, excludes them, fits the good data, then adds in the outliers corrected to fit the good data.  The best fit appears to be a simple cubic function although I did try a [sigmoid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134869/363): `y = c + (d - c)/(1 + Exp[a + b x])`.

Outliers can be selected with variations on `"stddev" -> 2` or `"stddev" -> {2}` to select outside or within band 2 respectively.  The bands are [1, 2 & 3 standard deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) from the mean.

```
data = {{2, 25.4359}, {4, 25.1367}, {6, 24.8248}, {8, 24.8872},
   {10, 24.7134}, {12, 24.3019}, {14, 23.2648}, {16, 22.7794},
   {18, 22.0979}, {20, 10.3315}, {22, 9.7597}, {24, 20.087},
   {26, 7.748}, {28, 17.3949}, {30, 5.952}, {32, 16.0672},
   {34, 15.084}, {36, 13.8762}, {38, 12.9525}, {40, 12.0011},
   {42, 11.1282}, {44, 10.1519}, {46, 9.56525}, {48, 8.80683},
   {50, 8.18156}, {52, 7.02375}, {54, 6.96017}, {56, 6.20118},
   {58, 5.57019}, {60, 5.82191}, {62, 5.61341}, {64, 5.40499},
   {66, 5.22668}, {68, 5.27839}, {70, 5.83658}};

ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

```
outliers[data_, OptionsPattern["stddev" -> 2]] := Module[{},

   {sd1, sd2, sd3} = Map[2 (CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], #] - 0.5) &,
     {1, 2, 3}];

   Clear[x];

   lm = LinearModelFit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x];

   getseries[sd_] := Module[{cb},
     cb = lm["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> sd];
     {lower, upper} = Transpose[cb /. x -> # & /@ First /@ data];
     p1 = Position[MapThread[#1 <= #2 <= #3 &,
        {lower, Last /@ data, upper}], True];
     Extract[data, p1]];

   If[ListQ[sd = OptionValue["stddev"]],
    o1 = Switch[sd,
      {1}, getseries[sd1],
      {2}, Complement[getseries[sd2], getseries[sd1]],
      {3}, Complement[getseries[sd3], getseries[sd2]],
      _, Print["\"stddev\" -> {2} used"];
      Complement[getseries[sd2], getseries[sd1]]],
    If[sd === None, o1 = data,
     s1 = getseries[Part[{sd1, sd2, sd3},
        Switch[sd, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,
         _, Print["\"stddev\" -> 2 used"]; 2]]];
     o1 = Complement[data, s1]]];

   {bands68[x_], bands95[x_], bands99[x_]} =
    Table[lm["SinglePredictionBands",
      ConfidenceLevel -> cl], {cl, {sd1, sd2, sd3}}];

   {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@
     Transpose[data];

   scale[min_, max_, a_] := {(1 + a) min - a max, (1 + a) max + a min};

   {xmin1, xmax1} = scale[xmin, xmax, 0.05];
   {ymin1, ymax1} = scale[ymin, ymax, 0.2];
   {xmin2, xmax2} = scale[xmin, xmax, 0.1];

   Print[Show[ListPlot[data],
     Plot[{lm[x], bands68[x], bands95[x], bands99[x]},
      {x, xmin1, xmax1},
      Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}}],
     If[o1 != {}, ListPlot[o1,
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]], {}],
     AxesOrigin -> {xmin2, ymin1},
     PlotRange -> {{xmin2, xmax2}, {ymin1, ymax1}},
     ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True]]];

outliers[data, "stddev" -> {3}]
```

[image]

```
data = Complement[data, o2 = o1];
outliers[data, "stddev" -> None]
```

[image]

```
o3 = Transpose[{First /@ o2,
    lm["BestFit"] /. # & /@ Thread[x -> First /@ o2]}];

Print[Show[Plot[{lm[x], bands99[x]},
   {x, xmin1, xmax1}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}],
  ListPlot[o3,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]],
  ListPlot[data,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]],
  AxesOrigin -> {xmin2, ymin1},
  PlotRange -> {{xmin2, xmax2}, {ymin1, ymax1}},
  ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

interpolate median filtered data:

```
medinterp = 
  Interpolation[
   Transpose@{data[[All, 1]], MedianFilter[data[[All, 2]], 6]}];
```

now drop the furthest outlier from the interpolation and redo the interpolation:

```
data = Drop[data, 
   First@Position[data, 
     Last@SortBy[data, Abs[medinterp[#[[1]]] - #[[2]]] &]]];
medinterp = 
  Interpolation[
   Transpose@{data[[All, 1]], MedianFilter[data[[All, 2]], 6]}];
Show[{
  Plot[medinterp[x], {x, 2, 70}],
  ListPlot[data]}]
```

manually eval the above 4 times..

[image]

fill in the points we dropped based on the interpolation:

```
 ListPlot[Join[
   data, {#[[1]], medinterp[#[[1]]]} & /@ Complement[data0, data]]]
```

[image]

note for this example you might do the same using a model fit (to `Erf` maybe)

Answer (score 4):

An approach where each point is scanned and kept only if it is close enough from the previous one. The correction is done through an interpolating function on the good points.

```
threshold = 5;
i = 1; dataA = data;
l = Length@dataA;
While[i < l, 
 If[Abs[dataA[[i + 1, 2]] - dataA[[i, 2]]] < threshold
    , i++
    , dataA = Drop[dataA, {i + 1}]; l = Length@dataA
 ]
]
dataB = Complement[data, dataA];
if = Interpolation[dataA];
dataB2 = {#, if[#]} & /@ dataB[[All, 1]];
ListPlot[{dataA, dataB, dataB2}]
```

[image]

`dataA` is the list of good points, `dataB` the list of bad points, `dataB2` the list of corrected points.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach is to use the Median filter:

```
med = MedianFilter[data[[All, 2]], 4]
ListPlot[Transpose@{data[[All, 1]], med}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I don't want to change the "blue" data points in my example (they represent correct measurements), but only "correct" the red ones so that they "fit" with the blue data.

Comment: @mrz -- It is a naive view of data which imagines that some data points are exactly correct and others are completely wrong. All measurements are inaccurate though maybe by different degrees,

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no mention about the underlying *data generating process*, this answer is going to provide a simple way of distinguishing between *outliers* and *regular* data.

We'll assume that `data` (please evaluate the *original* expression before continuing) can be sensibly described by a [*sigmoid* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) like $f(x)=\frac{L}{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$ which can be written also as $log(\frac{L}{f}-1)=kx_0-kx$. Note, how the last relation can be estimated using *ordinary least squares* only if $L$ is known.

Without any *apriori* knowledge about $L$ (besides the assertion in *Wikipedia* that "*...L = the curve's maximum value*" ) we will allow the *user* to set the appropriate value of $L$ according to her/his judgement.

Namely the code will allow the user to influence the value of $L$ by varying `pL` in `(1 + pL ) ymax` (the percentage by which $L$ *exceeds* the maximum value in `data`).

The 'knobs' in `Manipulate` control `pL` (*f*) and the radius within which points are considered non-outliers (*r*). Higher values for *r* allow more distant points from the estimated sigmoid to be considered normal.

```
Manipulate[

 display[pL, r],

 {{pL, 0.008, "f"}, 10^-9, 0.2, 10^-6},
 {{r, 2, "r"}, 1, 11, 0.5},

 Initialization :> (

   With[{xs = Part[data, All, 1], y = Part[data, All, -1], Nn = Length[data]},
    With[{ymax = Max[y]},

      (* ests will be used to construct the estimated data *)
      SetAttributes[ests, Listable];

      (* the sigmoid function that is assumed to describe the data *)
      s[x_] := L/(1 + Exp[-k (x - xo)]);

      (* Manipulate's first argument *)
      display[pL_, r_] := Module[{lmf, sol, dataest, time, junk, x, points, mask, n},
        (* transform data *)
        With[{dt = Transpose[{xs, Log[(1 + pL ) ymax/y - 1]}]},

          (* ols on transformed data *)
          lmf = LinearModelFit[dt, x, x];

          (* retrieve point estimates of parameters k and xo *)
          {sol} = Quiet[Solve[Thread[lmf["BestFitParameters"] == {k xo, -k}]]];
          (* augment solution with the value of L provided by the user *)
          AppendTo[sol, L -> (1 + pL) ymax];

          (* function used to produce the estimated data *)
          ests[x_] := Evaluate[s[x] /. sol];

          (* estimated data *)
          dataest = Transpose[{xs, ests[xs]}];

          (* indicates those elements in data that are further away from dataest than r ie the outliers *)
          mask = MapThread[EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] > r &, {dataest, data}];
          (* the actual points that correct for the outliers *)
          points = Pick[dataest, mask, True];

          n = Length[points];

          If[
             (* provided there are outliers *)
             n > 0,

             ListPlot[
               (* data excluding outliers, outliers, repaired data *)
               {Pick[data, Not /@ mask, True], Pick[data, mask, True], dataest},
               Joined -> {False, False, True},
               PlotStyle -> {
                 {PointSize[Medium]},
                 {PointSize[Medium], Opacity[0.4], Gray},
                 {Thin, Dashed, Opacity[0.6], Red}
                },
               PlotLegends -> 
                 Column[{Row[{"f=", N[pL, {2, 9}]}], 
                   Row[{"r=", N[r, {2, 9}]}], 
                   Row[{"n=", n, 
                     Style[Row[{"(", N[100 n/Nn, {2, 9}], "%)"}], Small, Italic, Gray]}]}],
               Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[points]}}],

           (* otherwise display a message *)
           Column[{Row[{"No points"}], Row[{"f=", N[pL, {2, 9}]}], Row[{"r=", N[r, {2, 9}]}]}]]]]]]
  ),
  SynchronousUpdating -> False,
  SynchronousInitialization -> False,
  Deployed -> True
]
```

The legend of the plot displays the *current* values of the controls (*f* and *r*) and the *number of outliers* (*n*) currently identified (both in absolute numbers and as a percentage of the total number of elements in `data`).

[image]